# Derivatives in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm writing a program using opencv that does text detection and extraction.
Im using the Sobel derivative in order to do edge detection and have gotten the following result:

[image]

But I wish to get the following result:

[image]

(I appologize for the blurry image.)

The problem I'm having is the "blank areas" inside the edges "confuse" the algorithem I'm using so when the algorithem detects the "blank part" seperating between two lines from the lines themselves it gets confused and start running into the letter themselves instead of keepeing between two lines. This error, I believe would be solves by achieving the second result.

Anyone knows what changes i need to make? in the soble derivative? maybe use a different derivative?

Code:

```
Mat ProfileSeamTextLineExtractor::computeDerivative(){
    Mat img = _image;
    Mat gradiant_mat;
    int scale = 2;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_16S;

    GaussianBlur(img, img, Size(3, 3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);

    Mat grad_x, grad_y;
    Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;

    Sobel(img, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
    Sobel(img, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_y, abs_grad_y);
    /// Total Gradient (approximate)
    addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, gradiant_mat);

    return gradiant_mat;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Did I get this right: You want the letters enhanced by the filter, but not only their edges but the complete letter? So in the first image, e.g., there are a number of white circles with dark filling. What you're aiming for though is to get these as white circles with white filling?

Comment: Precisely. Just to be clear- the white circles are arabic letters.

Comment: For this moment the second image is looking just like the first image but slightly blurred and leveled, there are still dark filling. Is it really what you need? Why do you use Sobel? If you don't need gaps between edges just take original image (can you show it?).

Comment: @VitShiryaev, you are correct It does seem like it. I've tried using a bigger kernel in the guassian blur and it gives a better result. the original picture is turned to grayscale and the idea is finding the local min of the derivative map (given at hand) between two text lines. this is then faced by the problem i've just demonstrated, so in a sense the original image does not help me, i need to work on some sort of derivative map.

Comment: Can you tell us your initial task? Do you want by first step just split your handwritten text in to lines for better further recognition? I still can not understand reason for any derivatives here.

Comment: well the task itself is to implement an algorithem given by an article (if you wish i will post it even though im sure you will find it boring and tedious so i will summerize it.) and in the article they are using this derivative and later preforming another function on the derivative map that i have described before. in terms of recognition we already know where the lines are we are using this algorithem to creat a path between two lines.

Comment: What I understood so far of problem, it can be solved by first make it a binary image by thresholding, then flood-fill outer area with white and then take a not of image. You will get a filled letter with sharp edges and everything will be saved. Please show us original image also for further clarifications. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your final aim is. Do you eventually want a nice filled in version of the text so you can recognise the characters? I can give that a shot if that's what you are looking for.

This is what I did while trying to remove inner holes:
[image: Holes removal attempted]

For this one I didn't bother:
[image: No holes removed]

It fails at the edges where the text is cut off.

Obviously, I had to work with the image that had already gone through some processing. I might be able to give you more help if I had the original and produce a better output. You might not even need to use derivatives at all if the background is clean enough.

Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void printInnerContours (int contourPos, Mat &filled, vector<vector<Point2i > > &contours, vector<Vec4i> &hierarchy, int area);

int main() {
    int areaThresh;
    vector<vector<Point2i > > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Mat text = imread ("../wHWHA.jpg", 0); //write greyscale
    threshold (text, text, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    imwrite ("../text1.jpg", text);
    areaThresh = (0.01 * text.rows * text.cols) / 100;
    findContours (text, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    Mat filled = Mat::zeros(text.rows, text.cols, CV_8U);

    cout << contours.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        int area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        if (area > areaThresh) {
            if ((hierarchy[i][2] != -1) && (hierarchy[i][3] == -1)) {

                drawContours (filled, contours, i, 255, -1);
                if (hierarchy[i][2] != -1) {
                    printInnerContours (hierarchy[i][2], filled, contours, hierarchy, area);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    imwrite("../output.jpg", filled);

    return 0;
}

void printInnerContours (int contourPos, Mat &filled, vector<vector<Point2i > > &contours, vector<Vec4i> &hierarchy, int area) {
    int areaFrac = 5;

    if (((contourArea (contours[contourPos]) * 100) / area) < areaFrac) {
        //drawContours (filled, contours, contourPos, 0, -1);
    }
    if (hierarchy[contourPos][2] != -1) {
        printInnerContours (hierarchy[contourPos][2], filled, contours, hierarchy, area);
    }

    if (hierarchy[contourPos][0] != -1) {
        printInnerContours (hierarchy[contourPos][0], filled, contours, hierarchy, area);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the second sobel derivative, add, normalize (this may do the same as addWeighted), and then thresholding optimally.  I had results similar to yours with different threshold values.

Here's an example:

```
cv::Mat result;
cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::medianBlur(gray, gray, 3);
cv::Mat sobel_x, sobel_y, result;
cv::Sobel(gray, sobel_x, CV_32FC1, 2, 0, 5);
cv::Sobel(gray, sobel_y, CV_32FC1, 0, 2, 5);
cv::Mat sum = sobel_x + sobel_y;
cv::normalize(sum, result, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

//Determine optimal threshold value using THRESH_OTSU.  
//  This didn't give me optimal results, but was a good starting point.
cv::Mat temp, final;
double threshold = cv::threshold(result, temp, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY+CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::threshold(result, final, threshold*.9, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

I was able to clearly extract both light text on a dark background, and dark text on a light background.

If you need the final image to consistently be white background with black text, you can do this:

```
cv::Scalar avgPixelIntensity = cv::mean( final );
if(avgPixelIntensity[0] < 127.0)
    cv::bitwise_not(final, final);
```

I tried a lot of different text extraction methods and couldn't find any that worked across the board, but this seems to.  This took a lot of trial and error to figure out, so I hope this helps.